# How to retrieve a HANA Database field value on SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, hana

Hi I am new to SAPUI5 for my application I want place Login screen , In Login need to fetch a data from HANA database for authentication, Fields are Employee ID and Password . If entered data in a login screen must match with SAP HANA database field value ,if match found gives a message Login Successful, if the entered values not present in the HANA  database, it should shows a message Invalid Login.Anyone please help me how can I do this, or share any code to fetch and compare each HANA database field values in SAPUI5.

Thanks in advance
Prasad

Comment: This question is rather broad, basically a requirement dump. You may want to get a grip on SAPUI5 development first, by checking the tutorials and the developer documentation. Logon handling is a standard service for SAPUI5 applications, nothing that you have to build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 'Gateway oData services' to retrieve the data in your database and then consume on the frontend in your UI5 application

Comment: Can anyone please share me the sample code to perform above operation ..